# Run gpg from systemd script

Tags: ssh, systemd, gpg, gpg-agent

I wrote a wrapper for `rsync`. It connects to my host and makes a backup of my `$HOME` directory via `ssh`. I use `gpg-agent` for the `ssh` verification. My script works when called from a terminal emulator. It uses my pinentry-program to promt for the passphrase of my gpg key and then syncs via `ssh`.

Now I want to call it on every startup. I ususally use `systemd` for this. I added the following to `$HOME/.config/systemd/user/backup.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Back up user files on startup
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
Requires=network-online.target
RemainAfterExit=false
ExecStart=/bin/backup.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

And enabled its via `systemctl --user enable backup.service`.

The script is executed, and every the local part (reading/writing log file) works. However, connecting via `ssh` using `pass` or calling `gpg` does not work. Since I never get prompted for my passphrase.

How do I make `gpg-agent` work when calling it from a script during `systemd` startup?

Minimal example `backup.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh user@iii.ppp.iii.pp
```

gpg-agent.conf:

```
pinentry-program /usr/bin/pinentry-gnome3
enable-ssh-support
default-cache-ttl 86400
default-cache-ttl-ssh 86400
max-cache-ttl 86400
max-cache-ttl-ssh 86400
```

.zshrc:

```
GPG_TTY=$(tty)
export GPG_TTY
unset SSH_AGENT_PID
if [ "${gnupg_SSH_AUTH_SOCK_by:-0}" -ne $$ ]; then
  export SSH_AUTH_SOCK="$(gpgconf --list-dirs agent-ssh-socket)"
fi
gpgconf --launch gpg-agent
```